# jquery select 2 change dropdown width dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using jquery select 2 and need to reduce width of dropdown dynamically.

This is my code,

```
$('.myselect').select2();

$('.myselect').on('select2:open', function(e) {
       var width = $('.select2-dropdown').width();
       width -= 20;
       $('.select2-dropdown').attr('style', 'width: '+width+'px !important');
});
```

What I need to do is **reduce width of dropdown by 20px**. But tis code not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait 1ms :D And it's probably select2 event bug.
http://jsfiddle.net/4f3td9eL/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //code that's interacting with the dropdown
}, 1);
```